# How to reduce A'B'+AB'+BC'D' to simplest form?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I wish to reduce the expression $A'B'+AB'+BC'D'$ to its simplest form.

The notation for boolean variables $A,B,C,D$, for those who are not familiar, is :

$+$ for logical OR operation

$'$ for the logical NOT operation, and

$AB$ means $A$ logical AND $B$

The answer is B’ + C’D’, and my attempt at the solution is:

$A'B'(B+B') +AB'+BC'D'$

$\equiv AB'B+A'B'B'+AB'+BC'D'$

$\equiv A'+AB'+A'B'+BC'D'$

$\equiv A'+B'+A'B'+BC'D'$

Here I am stuck. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I did not downvote your problem, but it  is not very understandable as written. You should say up front that $A$, $B$, and so on are Boolean variables.

Comment: @kimchilover Please sir i edited the post please help

Comment: Someone can please help? i have been stuck for 1 hour

Comment: @IntegrateThis  Yes i am looking forward to answer thank you for edits and incoming answer i appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Observe that:
\begin{align*}
A'B' + AB' + BC'D'
&= (A' + A)B' + BC'D' & \text{Distributive Law} \\ 
&= (1)B' + BC'D' & \text{Inverse Law} \\  
&= (1 + C'D')B' + BC'D' & \text{Domination Law} \\ 
&= B' + B'C'D' + BC'D' & \text{Distributive Law} \\ 
&= B' + (B' + B)C'D' & \text{Distributive Law} \\ 
&= B' + (1)C'D' & \text{Inverse Law} \\ 
&= B' + C'D' & \text{Identity Law} \\ 
\end{align*}

Comment: Sir i dont understand domination law

Comment: Is it just that 1+anything is 1?

Comment: Thank you for solution!